# Canvas arc drawing strange shapes - coffeescript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, coffeescript, drawing

```
@.ctx.lineWidth = 20
@.ctx.moveTo(i.x, i.y)
@.ctx.arc(i.x, i.y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2)
```

[image]

Any reason why that code would make the image above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your version of the arc, and I find it difficult to understand what you are acctually asking. Therefore I made two versions, in order to visually show you what's happening.

You can look at them here!
**UPDATED JSFIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/hqB6b/2/

**HTML**

```
First with the line inside.

<canvas id="ex" width="300" height="300">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>

Second with NO line inside!

<canvas id="example" width="300" height="300">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var example = document.getElementById('example');
var ctx = example.getContext('2d');
var i = {x:100,
    y:100}
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
ctx.lineWidth = 1;

ctx.moveTo(i.x, i.y)
//HERE BEGINPATH IS USED AFTER MOVETO
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(i.x, i.y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2)
ctx.stroke();


var ex = document.getElementById('ex');
var ct = ex.getContext('2d');
var i = {x:100,
    y:100}
ct.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
ct.lineWidth = 1;

//HERE BEGINPATH IS USED BEFORE MOVETO
ct.beginPath();
ct.moveTo(i.x, i.y)
ct.arc(i.x, i.y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2)
ct.stroke();
```

Comment: Thanks, using moveTo before beginPath fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

use beginPath before creating a path, and use closePath after creating it.
Since closePath... closes the path back to the first point, you might want stroke or fill before or after closing the path depending on what you seek.

Comment: +1 - While this didn't solve the problem, I actually didn't know about close path (for some reason), so this helped me out.